# Adding gesture handlers to Vuforia samples

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, vuforia

i am new to vuforia. i was able to run the samples successfully.but none of the samples use these *gesture handlers(Pinch, rotate and drag)*. i wanted to apply these  gesture handlers in **User Defined Targets** of vuforia sample.

i was trying to add these gestures by using *GestureDetector class* , but couldn't figure out how to add to **User Defined Targets** of vuforia sample.

**is there a way to add these gesture handlers(Pinch , rotate and drag) to user defined targets of vuforia samples??**

this is the code for Gesture Handling  from *GestureDetector class*:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());
  }

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
  SGD.onTouchEvent(ev);
  return true;
}

 private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
  SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
   @Override
   public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
     scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
     scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));

     matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
     iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
     return true;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in UserDefinedTargetRenderer class there is a method named renderFrame which is called at every frame. the properties Rotate, scale and Translate are assigned to 3d model in renderFrame().

all you need to do is pass the scale value from your MainActivity to renderFrame()  in UserDefinedTargetRenderer class.

you need to pass the scale value to  this line:
     `Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrix, 0, kObjectScale, kObjectScale,
                    kObjectScale);`

Let me know the results